# Best operating system for the serious writer?

Tags: creative-writing, novel, publishing, formatting, self-publishing

Windows, Android, macOS or else?

Comment: I flagged this as opinion-based, because as it stands right now any answer will have to be opinion-based. I suggest rephrasing and clarifying the question, to better explain your problem and your needs.

Comment: Does anybody use a touch-screen to write anything longer than a mundane email? The OS that's correct for your work is the one you don't have to think about when working.

Comment: @Boba Fit I know a guy who writes his stories in his phone with a touchscreen. I don't understand it either.

Comment: It also depends a lot on what you're writing, due to specialised software - you use completely different tools for screenplays compared to mathematical or scientific papers/textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

The question you're asking doesn't really match the tags. Is this about the best OS for writing, or for DTP?

If you mean writing, then the only aspect I can think of that makes any difference is that you might want to use a keyboard rather than a cellphone's touchscreen. Other than that, anything capable of producing a text file will do. I can't imagine any OS not meeting that need. (I know professional writers who still use an editor from the 1980s that runs under DOS. Yes, plural - two such authors.)

If you mean DTP, then again the first thing that comes to mind is setup of the hardware. You want to see what you're doing on a nice, large screen, or better yet, two of them. I'm sure you'll find a good DTP program for any common OS for computers - Windows, Linux, MacOS. Not sure about Android because that's a system primarily for smartphones. Windows will probably give you the widest range of options since it's the most common one and therefore the one that programs most often have a version for, but I don't think it's likely to matter much. At least unless you already have a DTP program in mind, in which case, just check which systems it exists for.